# Cannot bring back all occurrances of a substring when i know more than one exists(TSQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm searching against a database, in which it has two tables. A table containing the ID, and a table which holds a large data string (i.e. application data, which is in JSON format if it makes any difference).

The Data looks something like this:

```
ID        AppData
-------   ----------------------
1111      {"$type":"Apply.Domain.Model","ThumbnailId":"c5948e9d-1111","FileName":"image06.jpg","Id":"cc3b21b5-4dc3-481e-ba06-7ee1a4caf51d"},{"$type":"Apply.Domain.Model","ThumbnailId":"c5948e9d-2222","FileName":"dispesn_image.jpg","Id":"cc3b21b5-4dc3-481e-ba06-7ee1a4caf51d"}
2222      {"$type":"Apply.Domain.Model","ThumbnailId":"4494329d-1111","FileName":"anIMAGe_232.jpg","Id":"cc3b21b5-aaa-481e-ba06-7434344af51d"},{"$type":"Apply.Domain.Model","ThumbnailId":"c5948e9d-2222","FileName":"anIMAGe_232.jpg","Id":"aaa2235-4dc3-481e-ba06-7ee1a4caf51d"}
```

I'm trying to find within this application data, sub-strings which are image file names,of which there could be more than one and output them as such:

```
ID        ImageName
---       ---------
1111     image06.jpg
1111     dispesn_image.jpg
2222     anIMAGe_232.jpg
2222     anIMAGe_232.jpg
```

I know ALL the file names in the appdata column will be contained within this specific string(quotation marks included):

```
"FileName":"anIMAGe_232.jpg","Id"
```

and I am currently able to extract the image file name (with some "quirks")using this

```
declare @firststring varchar(max), @secondstring varchar(max)  
set @firststring = 'FileName":"'
set @secondstring = '","Id":"';


  select  SUBSTRING(SerializedFormData, CHARINDEX(@firststring, SerializedFormData), 
             CHARINDEX(@secondstring, SerializedFormData) - CHARINDEX(@firststring, SerializedFormData))
```

this brings me back my image name:

```
FileName":"IMAGENAME.jpg
```

Brilliant, except My first quirk is that I can't seem to display it excluding the first bit 'Filename":" ' (*This particular issue has since been resolved thanks to JohnHC but kept in for future reference*).

The second is that this query doesn't seem to search through the whole appdata string, and as such only brings back the first instance it comes across i.e.

```
ID        ImageName
---       ---------
1111     image06.jpg
2222     anIMAGe_232.jpg
```

Any ideas as to why it won't search through the whole string?

much appreciation for any help given :)

Regards

Comment: you need to tag which RDBMs you are using sql-server (I am assuming due to LEN())? next you really should discuss how you want your result, include example data and desired output.  Are you just wanting to return records that have teh filename more than once use REPLACE and LEN() to determine that if you want to split your JSON string and return matching substrings as rows then you will need a method of looping/recursion if sql-server use a recursive cte there are lots of examples of that here on SO

Comment: @matt thank you for the comment. taken on board :) and edited original for more clarity. I'll also take a look into recursive cte's

Answer (score 0):

First problem, you're pulling back the CHARINDEX from @Firststring as your start (ie, where it finds 'Filename'. You need to use:

```
...CHARINDEX(@firststring, SerializedFormData)+ LEN(@firststring)...
```

Second, this will only work on the first iteration. Smarter minds (with more free time) will be able to point you in the direction of how best to resolve issue 2.

Comment: Thank you! I also had to add   " -  LEN(@firststring)" to the end of it as the tail end was getting extra characters, but at least part 1 has been resolved!